# Making a button that shows an alert

Tags: html

I want to make a button that when you click on it to make an alert. I tried this `<button onclick="alert("hi")></button>` but it doesn't work and my code editor says there are problems in the code

Comment: Fix your quotes `"alert("hi")`

Comment: onclick="javascript:alert('hi')"

Comment: @TheBombSquad `javascript:` isn't needed

Comment: @TheBombSquad Also it won't work, because it will mess up the closing and opening double-quotes. You need to use a single quote for the content or the `onclick` or escape the content quotes.

Comment: u see the different quote types right?

Comment: yes I see it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrectly wrapped in quotation marks.
Here is your code:

```html
<button onclick='alert("hi")'>click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example. Run the snippet below.

```js
function alertMe() {
alert("hi");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="alertMe();">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: This is good too

Answer (score 1):

It's your quotes:

```
<button onclick="alert('hi')">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thanks!